# Action of finite group vs action of the associated constant group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme over an arbitrary scheme $S$, let $G$ be a finite group and let $G_S$ be the constant group scheme over $S$ associated to $G$.

1. Given a group morphism $G\to Aut_{Sch/S}(X)$, how does one define the action of the constant group scheme $G_S$ on $X$?
2. Given an action of the constant group scheme $G_S$ on $X$, how does one define the group morphism $G\to Aut_{Sch/S}(X)$?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been answered in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4215318/how-does-a-finite-group-act-on-an-affine-scheme

Finite pullbacks and coproducts commute in the category of schemes **Sch/S**. With $G_S$ the constant group $S$-scheme associated to $G$ a finite group, we in particular have:
$$G_S = \coprod_{g \in G} S, \quad G_S \times_SX = (\coprod_{g \in G}S)\times_S X \simeq \coprod_{g \in G}(S\times_S X) \simeq \coprod_{g \in G}X$$

As such, a morphism $G_S\times_SX \rightarrow X$ uniquely corresponds to a scheme morphism $\coprod_{g \in G}X \rightarrow X$ and therefore to a family of morphisms $(f_g:X\rightarrow X)_{g \in G}$. In fact, these form an action (on a set) $G \rightarrow \textrm{Aut}_{set}(X)$ if and only if $G_S \times_S X \rightarrow X$ is a group scheme action.